# "Black medium right-pointing triangle" symbol not working on mac

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add this ⏵ symbol to a div using css.

I used the code

```
.mydiv:after {
     content: "\23F5";
}
```

This works fine on all Windows browsers I have tried it on, but on a mac you get a black square, presumably showing that it is not a recognised character.

To make sure it isn't just my font or anything like that, I created a blank page with the only code being:

```
&#9205;
```

Again, this worked on Windows, but not on a mac.

I think I can get around it by using the wider arrow symbol (content: "\23F5" seems to work), and then css transforms to scale it to look like I want.  However, that feels an awful hack.

Why does this symbol not work, is there a fix, or is there any sort of "web safe" list of glyphs?

Comment: I feel like pointing out for the sake of it, that your example symbol shows as an unknown character for me on Windows. You might want to avoid symbols like this is if they are crucial for your website displaying correctly. Not everybody will have fonts with the characters you need.

Comment: That's curious.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I suspect the answer to my question is going to be more how I know which symbols are like this and which to avoid, but most sites, eg http://graphemica.com/%E2%8F%B5 - don't seem to give any warning.

Comment: If you are going to use a symbol, it's best to load a library, such as [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), so that you don't have to rely on your users having the necessary font to support the symbol you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font of that specific `:after` pseudo-selector, such as:

```css
header nav ul li>a:not(:only-child):after {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji";
    opacity: .75;
    content: ' \23F7';
}
```

I had the same issue as you and, in my case, it worked.

If it still doesn't work, try changing the order of the fonts or even completely replacing the fonts with `Helvetica` or `Arial` or even `Monaco`.

**Note:** the font stack is taken from GitHub's stylesheet.