# Attribute content is not displayed correctly on MacOS

Tags: html, css, macos

I am using the following code to display this symbol "⏵", but on MacOS it is not displayed correctly.

```
.caret::before {
    content: "\23F5";
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
  }
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to get "content" to work on MacOS.

Comment: You should configure the fonts for your web. Not everyone have the fonts that you are trying to display on your website. So either set ```font-family``` for the symbol to display or simply avoid using it. There's no in-between. Refer to the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059852/black-medium-right-pointing-triangle-symbol-not-working-on-mac

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: .caret::before {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji";
    content: "\23F5";
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
  }